# If two vectors are linearly independent in real field, are they linearly dependent everywhere else?

Tags: vector-spaces

For example, I have two vectors $V = \{v_1,v_2\}$, and $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$. Because $\alpha_{1}v_{1}+\alpha_{2}v_{2}=\vec{0}$ if and only if $\alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} = 0$, so $v_1,v_2$ are said to be linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

But, is $V$ linearly dependent everywhere else? i.e. for some field $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Even ignoring the issue that there are general many ways to construe a set as a vector space over a given field, how about $v_1=1,v_2=i$, $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as mentioned in comments, the answer is no- as long as you take "bigger" fields, you might find that some vectors aren't independent there.
Let $v=(1,0), u=(0,1) $ . Then, as vector field over $\mathbb{R}$, they form a base(hence independent).However, over the complex field, $v=1,u=i$, and $-iv +u=0$